# How can I change every semicolon in every filename of every file in a folder and its subfolders to a dash?

Tags: filenames

How can I recursively change every semicolon in every filename of every file in a folder and its subfolders to a dash? (or even better, a space and then a dash)

Comment: Are you looking for a tool to do this or you need a way to implement it yourself?

Comment: I'd prefer a way to implement this myself, but a tool would be fine. Googling a bit, it seems like I should be able to do this from a terminal, but I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but this snippet should do the the trick:

`for f in $(find . -type f); do mv "$f" "${f/;/ -}"; done`